# How does "grep -rl 'string' ./" search through readable code in binary files? Can I view what it's viewing instead of seeing binary output?

Tags: linux, grep, binaryfiles, .so, human-readable

When I run the code "grep -rl 'my string' ./", I receive the output of file names that contain 'my string' in it. When I go to view that file using vi, it comes up as a lot of weird characters. I've tried viewing the code using hexdump and xdd also, and that just outputs it in 1s and 0s. How do I view the code that grep views? As in, how do I view the code with the readable code 'my string' in it? The file in this case is a .so file. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `strings` command - a unix command line tool that "looks  for  ASCII  strings in a binary file".

If you run `strings <your file name>` it will show all the printables there.

Source: `man strings`

Comment: The `strings` command can also look for Unicode strings and strings in other encodings.